# Query a mock Facebook SQL database for gender and location for a specific user returning 2 rows & 1 row with 2 columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How do I:

Query this to return the number of male friends living in Canada, and all the female friends for a given user:

A) Query that would return 2 rows -- one for each number, and,

B) Query that returns 1 row with 2 columns?

Table 1: `Profile` (`userID`, `profile_URL`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Gender`,`Current_Location`, `Birthdate`, `AboutMe`)

Table 2: `Location` (`userID`, `city`, `country`, `state`, `zipcode`)

Table 3: `Page` (`pageID`, `pageURL`, `pageName`, `likedBy_userID`)

Table 4: `FriendRelation` (`userID_1`, `userID_2`, `AreFriends`)

Table 5: `user_status` (`userID`, `statusID`, `status`, `URL`, `timestamp`)

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's possible in that way :
A :

```
declare @user varchar(100) -- given user
set @user = 'user1' --Replace by your userid 
select count(*) Nbr
from  
(
select r.userid_2 from Profile p inner join FriendRelation r
on p.userid=r.userid_1 and areFriends='true'  --OR 0/1
inner join location loc on loc.userid=r.userid_2
where p.userid=@user and loc.city='CANADA' and gender='Male' 
union
select r.userid_1
from  Profile p inner join FriendRelation r
on p.userid=r.userid_2 and areFriends='true'  --OR 0/1
inner join location loc on loc.userid=r.userid_1
where p.userid=@user and loc.city='CANADA' and gender='Male' 
) NbrMale
union
select count(*) Nbr
from  
(
select r.userid_2 from Profile p inner join FriendRelation r
on p.userid=r.userid_1 and areFriends='true'  --OR 0/1
inner join location loc on loc.userid=r.userid_2
where p.userid=@user and gender='Female' 
union
select r.userid_1
from  Profile p inner join FriendRelation r
on p.userid=r.userid_2 and areFriends='true'  --OR 0/1
inner join location loc on loc.userid=r.userid_1
where p.userid=@user and gender='Female' 
) NbrFemale
```

B :

```
    select * from (
declare @user varchar(100) -- given user
set @user = 'user1' --Replace by your userid 
select count(*) NbrMale
from  
(
select r.userid_2 from Profile p inner join FriendRelation r
on p.userid=r.userid_1 and areFriends='true'  --OR 0/1
inner join location loc on loc.userid=r.userid_2
where p.userid=@user and loc.city='CANADA' and gender='Male' 
union
select r.userid_1
from  Profile p inner join FriendRelation r
on p.userid=r.userid_2 and areFriends='true'  --OR 0/1
inner join location loc on loc.userid=r.userid_1
where p.userid=@user and loc.city='CANADA' and gender='Male' 
) NbrMale
union
select count(*) NbrFemale
from  
(
select r.userid_2 from Profile p inner join FriendRelation r
on p.userid=r.userid_1 and areFriends='true'  --OR 0/1
inner join location loc on loc.userid=r.userid_2
where p.userid=@user and gender='Female' 
union
select r.userid_1
from  Profile p inner join FriendRelation r
on p.userid=r.userid_2 and areFriends='true'  --OR 0/1
inner join location loc on loc.userid=r.userid_1
where p.userid=@user and gender='Female' 
) NbrFemale) CountGend
```